# Is there a way to dynamically change a CSS value?

Tags: html, css

I have an svg placed in a div, carefully placed [so it makes the illusion that everything is background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcPAv.png):

[image]

And using this for placement:

```
.waves-background{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-45vw;
  left:-40px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index:-500;
}
```

But if I change the window size [it breaks so easy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5pds.png):

[image]

Is there something that could save me so many media queries as to say "from this window width each "x" pixels change "x"vw from the bottom value of this class"? (I need the page to be responsive and am using bootstrap 5)

Comment: Can you manage with a backgroud-image and background-position: cover? https://jsfiddle.net/ac0uogf7/

Comment: I see the tags javascript html css, but you may want to further clarify the preferred approach. Do you want a solution focused on Bootstrap? Do you want to add minimum JS and tweak CSS or don't really care at all? What about adding libraries? Hope you get an answer!

Comment: Please add your HTML then we can see the context. If it were me, I'd create a div related to this svg then I wouldn't have to use negative values but instead place it positively in relation to an object nearby/in the same place. Without this you are positioning it relative to the next nearest relative element above it.

Comment: Use viewport relative units `vw` and `vh` to size your elements can help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I understand the question, but in CSS there is a function called `calc()`. Usage here would for example be: `width:calc(100vw - 45px);`

Other than that javascript can do pretty much anything. Target the element using `document.getElementById("yourElementId").style.width = "100px";` (here you can dynamically get other values using js like height and width of the client).